# Mongo Aggregate Multiple Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have four different collection on mongodb.

Collection 1 (user):

```
{
   id:'123',
   name:'user_name',
   cities:['1','2'],
   services:['1','2'],
   email:'mail@domain.com'
}
```

Collection 2 (services):

```
{
   service_id:'1',
   service_name:'Service Name 1'
},
{
   service_id:'2',
   service_name:'Service Name 2'
},
{
   service_id:'3',
   service_name:'Service Name 3'
},
{
   service_id:'4',
   service_name:'Service Name 4'
}
```

Collection 3 (prices):

```
{
   price_id:'1',
   service_id:'1',
   price:'£15'
   user_id:'123'
},
{
   price_id:'2',
   service_id:'2',
   price:'£25'
   user_id:'123'
},
```

Collection 4(cities):

```
{
   city_id:'1',
   city_name:'City Name 1'
},
{
   city_id:'2',
   city_name:'City Name 2'
},
{
   city_id:'3',
   city_name:'City Name 3'
},
{
   city_id:'4',
   city_name:'City Name 4'
},
```

I've tried to get a result like below but I couldn't.

```
{
  user_id:1,
  name:'user_name',
  cities:['City Name 1','City Name 2'],
  prices:[
    {
      service_name:'Service Name 1,
      price:'£15'
    },
    {
     service_name:'Service Name 2',
     price:'£25'
    }
  ]
  email:'mail@domain.com'
```

Before Collection.aggregate, I matched the records with their id using Collection.findOne or Collection.find for the expected result, and I got what I expected. I don't know if it's because MongoDB or node.js, but sometimes it returns an empty result, and that's a problem. What's the best way to get a result like that using collection.aggregate?

Thanks

Comment: `I've tried to get a result like below but I couldn't.` you should provide more details what you tried what didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to below aggregation : https://mongoplayground.net/p/z--wtO__TrK

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      id: "123",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "cities",
      "let": {
        "city_id": "$cities"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$city_id",
                "$$city_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "city_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "cities"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "services",
      "let": {
        "service_id": "$services"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$service_id",
                "$$service_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            //"service_id": 0
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "services"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$services",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "prices",
      "let": {
        "service_id": [
          "$services.service_id"
        ]
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$service_id",
                "$$service_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            //"service_id": 0
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "prices"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "services.price": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$prices.price",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "email": {
        "$first": "$email"
      },
      "cities": {
        "$first": "$cities"
      },
      "services": {
        "$addToSet": "$services"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

pipeline stages:

```
    match: to filter based on userid
    lookup: to get citi name
    lookup: to get service name
    unwind: as wehave multiple services we need to get exact price for given service so unwinding
    lookup: to get price based on matched service id
    addfields: project price under service 
    group: as we have unwinded services we need to rewind/group by user.
```